# How to change router paths programmatically?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm building a Ionic app using Angular and calling an API to get some results. According to a particular property of the response object (such as "mode"="0" or mode="1" I need to change paths defined in app routing module, in particular to dynamically change the home page.

I'd like appcomponent (starting component) to call the API and to check the mode, then passing some routes according to that property.

E.g.:

I'd like to have something like:

```
  if (mydata['mode']==="0") {
   this.appRoutes = [
    {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'firstPath',
    pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
    path: 'firstPath',
    loadChildren: './firstpath.module#FistPathModule'
    },
    {
    path: 'secondPath',
    loadChildren: './secondpath.module#SecondPathModule'
    }
  ]
 } else if (my_data['mode']==="1") {
   this.appRoutes = [
    {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'secondPath',
    pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
    path: 'secondPath',
    loadChildren: './secondpath.module#SecondPathModule'
    },
  ]
 }
```

Is there a way to do something like this inside the app-routing.module?
Hiding firstPath in the second case is possible as well?

Comment: The first idea that pops in to my mind its a route guard, but I found an interesting article that could fit for your need: https://medium.com/@davidgolverdingen/adding-routes-dynamically-to-lazy-loaded-modules-in-angular-a8daecfaebf9 , all the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a correct way to make changes in app-routing file for such requirement.
You can use Guard to implement this.

```
In your child route file do like this: 
 {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      }


Auth Guard file: 

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  mode: number;  **// You can save this mode variable into a common service and use it.**
  constructor() { }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {

    if(this.mode == 1) {
      return false;
    }else {
      return true;
    }

    }); 


  }


}
```